# Validation for joomla button

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I need help on Joomla admin panel validations.

I am using Joomla 2.5. I need validation on some Joomla buttons in the admin backend.
For example, when the "`Publish`", "`Unpublish`" or "`Delete`" buttons are clicked, I would like a popup confirmation message to appear saying "`Are you sure you want to unpublish?`"

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to insert it will take a little while so to get you started off, you could use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_delete() {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
    if (answer){
        //run delete script
    }
    else{
        //go back to previous page
    }
}
</script>
```

The use pull the function when the button is clicked on.

Here is a basic html version using the script >> http://jsfiddle.net/n56vt/

Comment: basically these buttons are coded by XML. so how to call javascript function?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Joomla.submitbutton = function(task){
        if(task == 'Unpublish'){
              var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
              if(answer){
                    submitbutton(task); // run the unpublish script on controller
              }
              else{
                    return false;
              }
        }

        submitbutton(task);
   }
</script>
```